# How to run 2 process in the same docker container or dyno?

Tags: docker, heroku

I would like to run 2 process within the same docker container or dyno .

Is this possible?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't compose them into a single container?

Comment: These are 2 completely separate APIs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku Dyno is very similar to a docker container, and have the same main principle: Run just **one** foreground process in each one.

Check this [post](https://linuxconfig.org/understanding-foreground-and-background-linux-processes) to understand what are foreground and background process.

[Docker official web says :](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)

> It is generally recommended that you separate areas of concern by using **one service per container**

With time, maybe you could achieve your goal: **Run multiple services in a container** (api in your case) in docker using [linux services](https://blog.frd.mn/how-to-set-up-proper-startstop-services-ubuntu-debian-mac-windows/), creating one process which will launch other child process or another workaround, but in **heroku** will not be possible, due to security restrictions and limited s.o commands.